# Удаление пробелов при считывании значений из файла в памяти

Tags: python, list

К сути вопроса:
У меня есть текстовый файл, который имеет большой набор данных класса float. Эти данные в последствии подаются как входные в виде списков, где каждая строка - это отдельный список. Но при считывании данных значений столкнулся с проблемой, что между значениями стоит абсолютно случайное количество пробелов, а решение должно быть универсальным и под другие файлы, в которых так же вылетает случайное количество пробелов. Общее у них - это количество строк и расположение данных, но их формат всегда разный. Идея моего решения была спарсить весь файл в один большой список и затем брать оттуда необходимые мне значения, но вот из-за пробелов не получается сделать это в split(' '), так как они везде стоят в разном количестве. Возникает вопрос: как можно в памяти компьютера привести значения в файле к одному формату не изменяя основной файл?
Ниже пример значений из файла (да, там есть отступы даже в начале) :

```
  345.892    523.746 537.121     485.391
219.452     429.722   927.193 558.012
 635.163    294.143  194.362     949.152
```

Мне необходимо привести их к одному формату и записать в список, чтобы получилось так (на примере первой строки) :

```
null_list = [345.892, 523.746, 537.121, 485.391]
```

И сразу возникает второй вопрос: на сколько правильно форматировать так достаточно большой файл значений в памяти компьютера?

Comment: `но вот из-за пробелов не получается сделать это в split(' ')` - используйте split() без параметров, он группы пробелов объединяет. Лишние пробелы в начале/в конце можно с помощью strip убирать. Что-то такое получается: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xI2kh.png

Answer (score 1):

```
s='''  345.892    523.746 537.121     485.391
219.452     429.722   927.193 558.012
 635.163    294.143  194.362     949.152'''

print([*map(lambda x:x.strip(), s.split())])
```

---

```
['345.892', '523.746', '537.121', '485.391', '219.452', '429.722', '927.193', '558.012', '635.163', '294.143', '194.362', '949.152']
```

Comment: `strip` с параметрами по умолчанию смотрит и табуляции тоже, как и `split`, поэтому не нужно никаких параметров и у `strip` тоже, как и у `split`

Comment: Да удаляет таб тоже, поправлю.

Comment: И вообще лямбда тут излишня: `print([*map(str.strip, s.split())])`

Comment: Да и стрип после сплита нет смысла делать, сплит без параметров сам съест все пробелы, в том числе в начале/в конце, только перед начальными пробелами появится пустой элемент (который эти пробелы отделяют). Нужно наоборот, сначала убирать пробелы лишние в начале/в конце, а потом уже делить на части.

Answer (score 0):

Предложу такой вариант:

```py
import re

s = '''
  345.892    523.746 537.121     485.391
219.452     429.722   927.193 558.012
 635.163    294.143  194.362     949.152
'''  # данные, считанные из файла

s = s.strip()  # удаляем пробелы в начале и в конце строки
numbers = [float(n) for n in re.split(r'\s+', s)]  # \s+ - любое количество пробельных символов от 1
```

Список `numbers`:

```
[345.892, 523.746, 537.121, 485.391, 219.452, 429.722, 927.193, 558.012, 635.163, 294.143, 194.362, 949.152]
```

`re.split()` использует в качестве разделителя шаблон регулярного выражения '\s+', поэтому сработает с любым количеством пробелов.